# using -fno-objc-arc still gives me Convert to ARC errors

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to update my project to use ARC and I use JSONKit so I went in the 'Build Phases' tab under 'Compile Sources' and added the argument '-fno-objc-arc' but I still get errors all over the place.  I thought that was suppose to prevent this from happening?

What am I missing on this?

Comment: So you did the automatic conversion? Was JSONKit converted too or did you skip or exclude it? You don't add that flag until the project is converted, not before hand.

Comment: I actually killed JSONKit and used NSJSONSerialization instead, but I am going through ASIHTTPRequest and flagging things.  Automatic conversion won't run until all issues are resolved.  I needed to do a clean then a build and the run the arc conversion check and it seems to be working

Comment: I believe what I did was first remove stuff I didn't want the automatic converter to fool with, then run the converter, then add the other stuff back (open source projects etc). Its been a year since I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correctly how you implement it. What files did you include that flag on.

I am using AFNetworking and I had to put that flag on each file that AFNetworking had me include.

[image: Screenshot of -fno-objc-arc]

Adding to each file allowed the arc processor to ignore these files.

are you sure it is all lower case and that there are no spaces in the wrong places?